# Inconsistent SSL error when accessing different sites

Tags: c#, https, webclient, tls1.2

This is not one of the "why does my code not download over HTTPS" questions. I have seen and read all of them years ago, and since then I have implemented this same approach a number of times, successfully.

My very simple C# code that targets 4.7.1 framework and runs on 4.7.2 framework attempts to download resources over HTTPS. It follows all commonly known recommendations as regards to configuring `ServicePointManager`, `WebClient`, and `WebRequest`. Initially, I tested it with an Apache 2.4.20 instance on our LAN, and it worked fine. Next, I tested it with a couple of other servers on the public Internet, and there I ran into the error that occurs about 5 seconds after making the request, even though the page opens in a browser instantaneously:

```
{"The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."}
```

I checked the server certificates. They are trusted by Mozilla and Windows and open in any browser known to me, in a fully trusted mode. The sites respond over TLS 1.2. There is nothing visibly wrong with the servers or their certificates. For a sanity check, I took Google's homepage address https://www.google.ca/?gws_rd=ssl, and it opened just fine. Some sites open, other sites do not. I tried enabling one TLS version at a time, and each worked equally well with each of the working sites, whereas none of them worked with the non-working sites.

Here is my code. It is written to be used with basic auth but tested without it as well. This is not an authentication issue.

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11; // | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3; // tested by enabling only 1 protocol at a time locally. Each worked.

if (ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback == null) // for testing only
{
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (se, cert, chain, sslerror) => { return true; };
}

using (var client = new WebClientEx()) // Ex adds Timeout and CookieContainer
{
    client.CachePolicy = new System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy(System.Net.Cache.RequestCacheLevel.BypassCache);
    client.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

    var cc = new CredentialCache();
    // Using one or the other, depending on the situation, or none
    //cc.Add(url, "Basic", new NetworkCredential(user, pass));
    //cc.Add(new Uri(url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)), "Digest", new NetworkCredential(user, pass));
    client.Credentials = cc;

    return client.DownloadData(url);
}
```

Before falling back onto `WebClient`, I have tried with the plain `HttpRequest` for the sake of its reliable timing out, which is important for my implementation:

```
var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
req.Timeout = (int)timeout.TotalMilliseconds;
req.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate; // tried with or w/o

var encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes($"{user}:{pass}"));
req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded); // tried with or w/o

var credentialCache = new CredentialCache();
credentialCache.Add(url, "Basic", new NetworkCredential(user, pass)); // tried with or w/o
req.Credentials = credentialCache;
req.PreAuthenticate = true; // tried with or w/o
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        response.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(ms);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Both variants of my code equally worked with my local Apache and Google but did not work with some other sites. I cannot find any faults with my code. One of the sites that did not work is https://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/Basic/ that opens fine in any browser. This is the site that most of our software uses for unit testing, so I am expected to produce something that works with it during the test phase and with any arbitrary web server out there in production.

I turned on `System.Net` tracing and compared the successful and failed download attempts, and the difference is that one proceeds with the handshake while the other fails right away. There is no useful info in the trace.

Any ideas what is amiss?

All services and technologies mentioned in this question are beyond my control and have to remain whatever they currently are. I am powerless to change any versions or to install any updates. It has to work the way it currently is. If you are not happy with it, please skip over to other questions.

Comment: Use a tool like Wireshark to analyze the handshake packets and the cause should be clear when you compare succeeded/failed scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "nothing is wrong with the code". Something is actually wrong with those select servers that I had to test with. They are old or niche, and they are non-compliant to a degree that .NET framework refuses to interoperate with them. As soon as I tested with modern, compliant servers, everything worked as expected, both over HTTP or HTTPS and both with basic or digest authentication.